# Error: match word in file

Tags: python

There are two sentences in "test_tweet1.txt"

```
@francesco_con40 2nd worst QB. DEFINITELY Tony Romo. The man who likes to share the ball with everyone. Including the other team.
@mariakaykay aga tayo tomorrow ah. :) Good night, Ces. Love you! >:D<
```

In "Personal.txt"

```
The Game (rapper)
The Notorious B.I.G.
The Undertaker
Thor
Tiësto
Timbaland
T.I.
Tom Cruise
Tony Romo
Trajan
Triple H
```

My codes:

```
import re
popular_person = open('C:/Users/Personal.txt')
rpopular_person = popular_person.read()
file1 = open("C:/Users/test_tweet1.txt").readlines()
array = []
count1 = 0
for line in file1:
    array.append(line)
    count1 = count1 + 1
    print "\n",count1, line
    ltext1 = line.split(" ")
    for i,text in enumerate(ltext1):
        if text in rpopular_person:
            print text
    text2 = ' '.join(ltext1)
```

Results from the codes showed:

```
1 @francesco_con40 2nd worst QB. DEFINITELY Tony Romo. The man who likes to share the ball with everyone. Including the other team.
Tony
The
man
to
the
the

2 @mariakaykay aga tayo tomorrow ah. :) Good night, Ces. Love you! >:D<
aga
```

I tried to match word from "test_tweet1.txt" with "Personal.txt".

Expected result:

```
Tony
Romo
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

you need to split `rpopular_person` to get it to match words instead of substrings

```
rpopular_person = open('C:/Users/Personal.txt').read().split()
```

this gives:

```
Tony
The
```

the reason Romo isn't showing up is that on your line split you have "Romo."  Maybe you should look for rpopular_person in the lines, instead of the other way around. Maybe something like this

```
popular_person = open('C:/Users/Personal.txt').read().split("\n")
file1 = open("C:/Users/test_tweet1.txt")
array = []
for count1, line in enumerate(file1):
    print "\n", count1, line
    for person in popular_person:
        if person in line:
            print person
```

Comment: @ThanaDaray Try the added code, see if that gives what you want

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be that `rpopular_person` is just a single string. Therefore, when you ask things like `'to' in rpopular_person`, you get a value of `True`, because the characters `'t', 'o'` appear in sequence. I am assuming that the same goes for `'the'` elsewhere in Personal.txt.

What you want to do is split up Personal.txt into individual words, the way you're splitting your tweets. You can also make the resulting list of words into a `set`, since that'll make your lookup much faster. Something like this:

```
people = set(popular_person.read().split())
```

It's also worth noticing that I'm calling `split()`, with no arguments. This splits on all whitespace--newlines, tabs, and so on. This way you get everything separately like you intend. Or, if you **don't** actually want this (since this will give you results of "The" all the time based on your edited contents of Personal.txt), make it:

```
people = set(popular_person.read().split('\n'))
```

This way you split on newlines, so you only look for full name matches.

---

You're not getting "Romo" because that's not a word in your tweet. The word in your tweet is "Romo." with a period. This is very likely to remain a problem for you, so what I would do is rearrange your logic (assuming speed isn't an issue). Rather than looking at each word in your tweet, look at each name in your Personal.txt file, and see if it's `in` your full tweet. This way you don't have to deal with punctuation and so on. Here's how I'd rewrite your functionality:

```
rpopular_person = set(personal.split())
with open("Personal.txt") as p:
    people = p.read().split('\n') # Get full names rather than partial names
with open("test_tweet1.txt") as tweets:
    for tweet in tweets:
        for person in people:
            if person in tweet:
                print person
```

Comment: My fault. yes as you said "Romo." It showed after remove special character but "The" also showed. Any suggest?

Comment: @ThanaDaray "The" is in your Personal.txt file, so it's going to get matched. If you only want to match full names, split Personal.txt on just the newline character (`'\n'`).